# How to use try catch to get errors from New-ComplianceSearchAction

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to create a try catch for a certain exception, for New-ComplianceSearchAction, but till now no success.

Any one know how can I deal with this error from that command?

This is the error that I want to handle:

> Unable to execute the task. Reason: The search "asd" is still running
> or it didn't return any  results. Please wait until the search
> finishes or edit the query and run the search again.
> + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-ComplianceSearchAction], ComplianceJobTaskException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=VI1EUR03WS021,RequestId=e0c617b6-2906-4d24-8da8-93b49aba6405,TimeStamp=4/24/2023
> 3:24:56 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ComplianceJobTaskException]
> 5B1778A4,Microsoft.Office.ComplianceJob.Tasks.NewComplianceSearchAction
> + PSComputerName        : eur03b.ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com Unable to execute the
> task. Reason: The search "asd" is still running or it didn't return
> any results. Please wait until the search finishes or edit the query
> and run the search again.
> + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-ComplianceSearchAction], ComplianceJobTaskException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=VI1EUR03WS021,RequestId=e0c617b6-2906-4d24-8da8-93b49aba6405,TimeStamp=4/24/2023
> 3:24:56 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ComplianceJobTaskException] 5B1778A4,Microsoft.Office.ComplianceJob.Tasks.New
> ComplianceSearchAction
> + PSComputerName        : eur03b.ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com

And this is the code that I am using, to catch this error, or even any:

```
### CONTENT SEARCH - EXPORT
Write-Output "Content Search - Export: started"
$search_name = 'asd'
# Exports and create the Search results key and url
try {
    $ExportDetails = New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "$search_name" -Export -ExchangeArchiveFormat PerUserPst -Format FXStream -IncludeCredential -ErrorAction STOP
}
catch [ComplianceJobTaskException] {
    Write-Host "An error occurred while running the command."
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message -ErrorAction STOP
    exit    
}
```

Comment: In short: `try` / `catch` only acts on _terminating_ errors, whereas it is far more typical for cmdlets to report _non-terminating_ errors. For the `catch` block to get invoked, non-terminating errors must be promoted to terminating ones by passing `-ErrorAction Stop` or by setting `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` beforehand. See the linked duplicate for more information.